# Autcorrelation Via FFT and Zero Padding MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I would like to understand conceptually why when calculating the Autocorrelation Function of a vector x via fft, the best way is to zero padding in the way

```
nFFT = 2^(nextpow2(length(x))+1); 

% nFFT = 2*length(x) will do it as well

F = fft(x-mean(x),nFFT);
```

and not, for instance

```
nFFT = 2^(nextpow2(length(y)));
```

Why do the way we pad the vector influence so much the approximation of the Autocorrelation Function?

Thank you.

Comment: How many non-zero samples will the autocorrelation of a length-n sequence be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't zero pad enough (to 2X or more than the original length), an FFT fast convolution correlation produces a circular autocorrelation, not a linear autocorrelation, which is usually what is desired.